# get column and bind it to drop down list C#

Tags: c#, wcf, stored-procedures, drop-down-menu, desktop-application

I Have WCF service setup with 5 projects for different layers such as DAL, desktop, model, interface and service. BAL is using stored procedure from DAL which retrieves data stored in database. How do I call the the database list from the BAL located in the service to display data on the form in drop-down list.

Here is my BAL:

```
public class GenderBAL
{
    public Genders GetGenders(Int32 id) 
    {
        Genders item = null;
        using (GenderTableAdapter ad = new GenderTableAdapter())
        {
            using (mHotRes.DAL.dstGender.GenderDataTable tbl = new DAL.dstGender.GenderDataTable())
            {
                ad.GetGendersInfo();
                if(tbl.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    mHotRes.DAL.dstGender.GenderRow row = tbl[0];
                    item = new Genders();
                    item.GenderId = row.GenderId;
                }
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

}

Here is my Form:

```
private void FillLookups()
    {
       try
        {
            IHotRes res = new MHotServiceProvider().Service;
            ddlGender.DataSource = res.GetGenders(1);
            ddlGender.DataSource = "Gender";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageHelper.ShowErrorMessage(ex);
        }
```

Comment: just add `ddlGender.DataBind();` after this line : `ddlGender.DataSource = res.GetGenders(1);` and remove this line : `ddlGender.DataSource = "Gender";`

Comment: @UZIERSKI I think you are looking for how to bind value and text to dropdown

Comment: @ChandrashekarJupalli I just want to get value from the database and bind it to the drop-down list. The code for form is not fully correct I have error appearing to do with the `ddlGender.DataSource = res.GetGenders(1);`

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava 'ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) -- this is the error I receive after adding `ddlGender.DataBind()`

Comment: Sorry use this code `ddlGender.DisplayMember = "Gender";` instead of `ddlGender.DataSource = "Gender";`.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava yes however in visual studio for the winforms you would use ComboBox to make a drop down list. `ddlGender` is just a name of the combobox and in properties you change DropDownStyle to DropDownList. Maybe there is other way but I always made it this way.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava I think the problem is within the previous line as when I run the application it points to that line. The error message is at the compilation time but it is long to include it in here unless I include the image.

Comment: This error message sometimes appears and sometimes it don't but the main problem is that the drop down list is empty and it should return column from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not trying to retrieve ID you are trying to retrieve a list from the database that's why the code should look like this for the BAL:

```
public class GenderBAL
{
    public List<Genders> GetGenderList() 
    {
        List<Genders> gender = null;
        Genders itm = null;
        using (GenderTableAdapter adp = new GenderTableAdapter())
        {
            using (DAL.dstLookup.GenderDataTable tbl = adp.GetGenderDataList())
            {
                if(tbl.Count>0)
                {
                    gender = new List<Genders>();

                    foreach(var row in tbl)
                    {
                        itm = new Genders();
                        itm.GenderId = row.GenderId;
                        itm.Gender = row.Gender;
                        gender.Add(itm);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return gender;
    }
}
```

}

Also change all your layers to where you have used `Genders GetGenders(Int32 id)` to get the list as mentioned above.

For Desktop layer also call the list and remember that combobox needs three properties to be set up which are `ValueMember`, `DisplayMember` and `DataSource`. Next time read about different properties before using them. The code for the form should be this:

```
IHotRes res = new MHotServiceProvider().Service;
ddlGender.ValueMember = "GenderId";
ddlGender.DisplayMember = "Gender";
ddlGender.DataSource = gender;
```